# visual svn new files don't get added to subversion automatically

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I am using visual studio - visual svn. My problem is that new files don't get added to subversion automatically, and I have to add them manually which is a bourdon and causes code issues on the programmers end. 
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You mean that the added files don't show in "Pending Changes" ?

Comment: yes, they are not part of subversion automatically. Not till I right click each of them and choose "Add to Subversion" option..

Comment: I don't know if it's an option for you: change from Visual SVN to AnkhSVN. I'm using Visual SVN for the SVN Server and AnkhSVN in Visual Studio and never had this kind of problem.

Comment: @mashtagidi what kind of projects do you work with (i.e. what's the template of the project)? What VisualSVN version do you have? What Visual Studio version do you have?

Comment: @bahrep I am working with Visual svn 4.1.10 on Visual studio 2013. My solution is combined with Mvc and Wcf and the client is Angular js which is seperated from my server solution.

Comment: Reinstalling had originally fixed this issue from me however a week later this issue has returned. I have sent an email to the VisualSvn team and hopefully they can rectify this.